# Set https support for Akka server with .ca-bundle, .crt and .key files

Tags: scala, ssl, akka-http

I have a simple Akka http server, but I have to set https support. 
I have three files for the certificate : .crt, .key and .ca-bundle
In Akka doc, there is only PKCS12 example. 
How can i do with the files that I have ?

```
def initializeWebServer(interface: String,
                          port: Int) = {

        val route : Route =
          pathPrefix("secured") {
            authenticateOAuth2(realm = "secure site", checkAuthentication){ token =>
            concat(
              get{
                path("hello"){
                  complete("hello world")
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface, port.toInt)
    CoordinatedShutdown(system).addJvmShutdownHook({
      bindingFuture
        .flatMap(_.unbind())
    })
  }

  def myUserPassAuthenticator(credentials: Credentials): Option[String] =
    credentials match {
      case p@Credentials.Provided(id) if p.verify("secret") => Some(id)
      case _ => None
    }

  def checkAuthentication(credentials: Credentials): Option[String] = credentials match {
    case p @ Credentials.Provided(token) if p.verify("secret") => Some(token)
    case _ => None
  }
```

Comment: If you're open to a solution with the SSL cert in `PKCS #12` format, this [`blog post`](https://blog.genuine.com/2018/03/https-redirection-with-akka-http/) which includes steps for cert conversion via `openssl` might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's to @Leo C 's comment,

- Convert key and crt to p12 :

  openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.p12 -inkey server.key -in server.crt
- Implementation of the solution with SSL : 
  [https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html](http://Akka%20HTTPS)

Comment: Thanks. Now SSL replaced by TLS v1.2 or v1.3, and by this fact SSL is not recommended. Also there is OWASP recommendation: Verify that known ... padding modes (i.e. PKCS#1 v1.5, etc.) ... are not used unless required for backwards compatibility.